# Display Records Horizontally Instead of Vertical in Cells, SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm trying to display multiple values for one drive by adding a column for each additional record assigned to a drive. For example, a drive ID is unique but can have multiple promotional incentives assigned to it.

For example, if we go to a university on 1/23/2015, that will a unique event or record in the DriveMaster table, but if we are giving away T-Shirts and Pizza, those two records will be assigned to the drive in the EquipmentDetail table.

In SSRS, I'm trying to create a sub-report that will display the promotional items on one line instead of adding additional lines for each promotional item.  See screenshot below.

[image]

What I'd like to have happen is have the each drive only account for 1 row, and each promotional item listed in a new column to the right.  See mockup in Excel.

[image]

Is there a way to handle this?  I know there is in Crytal Reports, but I can't figure this out in SSRS. I've tried using a Matrix, but I can't see to get the columns to grow if there are multiple incentives.

I added a column group on the Description field, and it looks like that it is close, but that the grouping will create blank spaces (cells) in it.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a [Column Group](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334(v=sql.100).aspx) for your promotional item in your Matrix.

Hope that helps.

Edit:

It looks like there are some areas that contain no data (because of your groupings)

We can do something like the following:

In your query you can use the '[over](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)'

```
Select DriveID, PromotionItem, ... , 

ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by Select DriveID, PromotionItem, ... Order by PromotionItem) 
AS ColumnGroupNumber
```

Then in the Promotion Item group that you have change the field it groups on to the ColumnGroupNumber (or whatever you are going to call it). Just don't change the field in the detail row, or you will not see the details.

I have used this solution before. I found it [here](http://jessicammoss.blogspot.com/2010/04/different-items-per-ssrs-column-group.html).

Comment: I was able to add a Column Group, but now I'm seeing an issue where it creates blank cells in columns when grouping.  Is there a way to remove those?

Comment: By the cell is empty do you mean the entire: Row, Column, or just a cell. The cell will be blank if there is corresponding data in the row or other columns with no data for that particular matching. If there should be something in that cell when there is not, take a look at your row groupings (if any) and the data itself. However, if your 'DriveID 123' Only had Promotion 1 and not Promotion 2 it will be blank; unless you have an expression like `=IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value IS NOTHING,"0",Fields!FieldName.Value)`